# folder.getFiles is not a function error in Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-drive-api, typeerror

When I run my function in Apps Script its working fine but when I add it in a **trigger** this error always occurs in first run.

> TypeError: folder.getFiles is not a function

This is the code. I use this code to get all files in all folders and subfolders.

```
var level=0;
function getFnF(folder) {
  var folder= folder || DriveApp.getFolderById('root folder ID');
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('google sheet ID');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('List');
   

  var files=folder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    var fileid = file.getId();
    var TimeStamp =   Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    var filesize = file.getSize()/ 1024 / 1024;
    var lastrow = sh.getLastRow();
    var filename =file.getName();

    sh.appendRow([TimeStamp,lastrow,filename,file.getName(),filesize.toFixed(2),fileid);
    Logger.log('Item added in list: ['+ lastrow+"] " + filename);
  }
  var subfolders=folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder=subfolders.next();
    //subfolders only
    level++;
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: In your situation, when `var folder= folder || DriveApp.getFolderById('root folder ID');` is modified to `var folder= DriveApp.getFolderById('root folder ID');`, is that the result you expect?

Comment: when I modified it to `var folder= DriveApp.getFolderById('root folder ID');` it will work in trigger but the function will not iterate over subfolders. See the last part of the code `getFnF(subfolder);`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: No worries. Thanks to you I solved my problem. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `When I run my function in apps script its working fine but when I add it in a trigger this error always occurs in first run.`, I'm not sure about the kind of trigger. But when the function is run by a trigger, the event object is given to the 1st argument. So, in this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var level = 0;
function getFnF(e, folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('root folder ID')) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('google sheet ID');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileid = file.getId();
    var TimeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    var filesize = file.getSize() / 1024 / 1024;
    var lastrow = sh.getLastRow();
    var filename = file.getName();
    sh.appendRow([TimeStamp, lastrow, filename, file.getName(), filesize.toFixed(2), fileid]);
    Logger.log('Item added in list: [' + lastrow + "] " + filename);
  }
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder = subfolders.next();
    //subfolders only
    level++;
    getFnF(e, subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}
```

- By this modification, when the function `getFnF` by a trigger, the function is run as the initial value of `folder` of `DriveApp.getFolderById('root folder ID')`.
- By the way, when you want to run this function from another function instead of the trigger, please call this as `getFnF("dummy", folder)`.

Comment: I didn't know that its possible. Thank you @Tanaike 

Comment: Thank you I'll remember this `getFnF("dummy", folder)`

Comment: @Michael Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.